# Increment a field in model using remote method in loopback?

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, loopbackjs, strongloop

There is a field called counter in a model and whenever if I call a custom remote method like

```
Request URL
http://loopback:3000/api/models/increment_counter

Request body 
EMPTY

Response
{
   "counter" : [Value after Increment]
}
```

Currently to increment First i have to get the counter value from db and increment it one and update the couter value, This involves two queries, Is it possible to do it in a single NodeAPI call like the below mysql query.I am currently using Mysql as DB.

```
mysql_query("
    UPDATE model 
    SET counter = counter + 1
    WHERE model_id = '1'
");
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the MySQL syntax you want, you seem to need an **atomic counter**.

### database transactions

With the MySQL connector, you can use [database transactions](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Using-database-transactions.html). It is supported by the MySQL connector. It's a bit overkill for just atomic counters but it will get the job done.

Here is an example, inside a custom remote method

```
MyModel.someRemoteMethodForIncrementing = function(callback) {
  // Start the transaction
  MyModel.beginTransaction({
    isolationLevel: MyModel.Transaction.READ_COMMITTED
  }, function(err, tx) {
    // Retrieve the current counter value as part of the transaction
    MyModel.findById(id, {
      transaction: tx
    }, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return tx.rollback(function(err) {
          callback(err);
        });
      }

      // Increment the counter as part of the transaction
      var inc = data.counter + 1;

      MyModel.updateAttributes({
        counter: inc
      }, {
        transaction: tx
      }, function(err, newData) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return tx.rollback(function(err) {
            callback(err);
          });
        }

        // Commit the transaction to make it happen
        tx.commit(function(err) {
          if (err) return callback(err);
          // Counter should have been incremented
          callback();
        });
      });
    });
  });
};
```

I haven't tested it but it should work, let me know

### extented operators

In the future, you will be able to use the [$inc (increment) extended operator](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/MongoDB-connector.html#additional-settings) but so far it's only supported by MongoDB connector, not MySQL.

Just for reference, here is the syntax (*works only with MongoDB*)

```
PUT api/Model/:id?filter={"$inc":{"name":propertyToIncrement, "count":incrementAmount}}
```

There is an ongoing [PR](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector/pull/64) that I am trying to get landed to get MySQL support, but there are [many things](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mysql/issues/206) to be done before it can get merged.

Comment: thanks for saying about $inc operator, But the problem is that I am using mysql, Which i forgot to say that in the question, I will add it

Comment: Don't worry I understood you were using MySQL ;) I should clarify my answer, the solution is using the database transaction. It will not be done in a single MySQL request, but it will be atomic, which in the end I suppose is what you want right ?

Comment: @sivashanmugamkannan I have updated my answer, you should be all set

Comment: Thanks you so much, Saved a lot of time .

Comment: This is looked fine, But this transaction produces and error "TypeError: Frame.updateAttributes is not a function"

Comment: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Using-database-transactions.html
.............Post.updateAttributes({content: 'c2', options, function(err, newPost) { ..............

The code has been mentioned in the loopback doc, Where the content:c2 attribute does't have Closed curly brace near 'c2'.....Even if i remove the closed curly brace in { counter: data.counter + 1 } in produces another error, Please execute and verify if possible.

Comment: @sivashanmugamkannan I honestly don't have the time to test this. But curly braces should only be required for properties of type String. Also I have seen your rejected proposed edit, good catch I updated my answer

Comment: I have updated the code to handle errors, it should help you debug it if needed

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it in a single loopback remote method call. Assume you are sending an Id in your request

```
yourModel.remoteMethod = function(data, cb){
    yourModel.findById(data.id, function(err, object){
      if(err){
        cb(err, null);
      }
      object.counter += 1;
      object.save(function(saveErr, afterSaveObj){
        cb(saveErr, afterSaveObj.counter);
      })
    });
}
```

here cb is a callback which loopback passes to your remoteMethod.

Comment: This is not atomic because it is making two distinct mysql queries. If there are N multiple requests executed in parallel, the counter will actually be incremented a lot less than N times.